# Spring Boot web Layer Test : Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin

I'm trying to setup some unit and integrations tests to my controller layer but for some reason nothing is working as it should be a very simple setup.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
    exclude = [DataSourceAutoConfiguration::class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration::class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration::class]
)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
internal class TermsResourceTest {

    private var termsService = mockk<TermsService>()

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    private val cut = TermsResource(termsService)

    @BeforeEach
    fun beforeAll() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(cut)
            .build()
    }

    @Test
    fun contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

When I run this it exits with an error in the UserDetailsServiceImpl (  Custom implementation of UserDetailsService )

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig'
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl' defined in file
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'pt.keymaster.kss.repository.UserRepository'
```

Does anyone know why is the context failing to load if everything should have be auto configured?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You've stated: "if everything should have be auto configured" but that's not true, see your `exclude` above. What is the reason for those exclusions?

Comment: Since I don't plan on running tests to the database layer and spring was complaining about not being able to find the database properties for the test profile I've decided to exclude them from the context. But at some point this will be removed